# Best way to define a string with line breaks and HTML?

Tags: php

I want to define a string as text with line breaks and HTML.

Reading through the various docs, it appears

```
$string = "Text
           Text <br>
           Text"
```

Will work. However, I've also seen `<<<EOF` referenced, and also `define()` to store the text as a constant.

What are the different use cases for each approach, and relative advantages/disadvantages?

The string/constant will be used to populate a template email message body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `\n`:

```
$string = "Text\nText";
```

Doing:

```
echo nl2br($string);
```

will turn:

```
Text\nText
```

into

```
Text<br>Text
```

In all honestly though, the best way to define linebreaks is by templating with PHP:

```
Hi, the title of my page is <?php echo $title; ?>.<br>
It was created on the <?php echo $formattedDate; ?>.
```

Using HTML in your PHP strings is just nasty, especially if you need to hand your work over to a designer.

Comment: The nl2br replaces '\n' with '<br>\n', you won't notice the remaining '\n', but something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Pakspul You're right. I didn't actually notice that!

Comment: to make it a little bit shorter use <?php=$title?> or even omit the `php`: <?=$title?> (though that should only be used if the only parser you run on that file is a php parser or else the tags could be interpreted by some other parser).